# What is this on my dogs face?

Tags: dogs, health, diseases

[image]

Any idea what that is on her face? Should I be concerned that it might be something serious?[image]

I added another picture. I hope it helps.[image][image]

Comment: Have you gone to vet? I think in this case it is best to visit a vet ASAP

Comment: Please touch the area with fingers and tell if it is more warm than surrounding skin.

Comment: Also can you please post another picture which directly focuses on the spot from top and not from one side?

Comment: To provide the information Sonevol asked for, please edit your question and write as if the information was there from the beginning (no new paragraph for each edit). Have a look at the [tour] to see how you can edit your question or add a comment. For more information, see the [help] topic [How to ask a good question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you gone to vet? I think in this chase it is best to visit a vet ASAP